# Create multiple orders in different tabs at same time (Magento)

Tags: php, magento

I want to create multiple orders in magento admin at same time(in different browser tabs). Normally when i open create new order page in two different tabs,  I choosed the two different customer (let's say in first tab I choose customer A, and in 2nd tab I choosed customer B). Then I add two products in first tab(customer A) and 
add 1 product into 2nd Tab (here is the problem). When I add 1 product into 2nd tab(Customer B) it shows the total 3 product in a cart(It merg the first tab products into 2nd tab).

In this scenario i want to create two orders one with Customer A (having 2 products in his order) and other is Customer B(should have only 1 product in his order).

As we know magento store the cart items in DB, so there should be solution for this to change the default  behaviour of  magento like this, Please guys help me on this. How i can do it? What approach i should follow to do this ?

It would be great if you guys gives any hint, suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you'd have to open up your 2nd+ windows in incognito/private mode, so each one can log in separately and get a different session cookie. since the cart is tied to a session, ANY windows sharing the same session will get the same cart.

Comment: @MarcB thanks for reply, but I know that if i open the 2nd+ windows in incognito mode then this issue will not be apear, but i want to do this functionality in same window with different tabs

Comment: there's no way for any website to know which of however many tabs you're using to access the site at any time. therefore it's not possible to have two tabs open and be treated as two different sessions, since by definition they'll be sharing the SAME session cookie between them. hence using incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you generate a unique key for each cart, you could use a url parameter to update/retrieve the cart instead of using the user or session. You'd simply append `?cart=someCartId` to every url.

Now, there are a couple of things to think about with that approach:

**Possible issues:**

- Because you pass `cart` in every link, if someone was to use the 'open in a new tab' option, it would still show the same cart. So it only works before creating the first cart, or when entering the website separately in each tab.
- If the `cart` parameter got lost somewhere, while browsing the site, so would the cart.

**Possible solution:**

Even though you'd allow having a separate cart open in each tab, it would still be good to allow the user to access any of his carts in any tab. This way you could create new carts if necessary, and easily find the cart you want if something broke.

**Final thoughts:**

Now, thinking about my solution... Wouldn't it just be a good decision to allow multiple carts per user in your case ? Think it through, see if you can adjust the UI. I think it would be way better to give the user the freedom to add any item to any of his carts regardless of the tab he is in. In fact, it will be easier to implement than 'one cart per tab', and it could save users a lot of confusion.